# Wpf Grid rows height is not calculated correctly with SizeToContent

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In the following example, there are two `Grid` rows with height of `6*` and `4*`. The problem is that only after the user changes the the size of the window, the correct height of the rows is calculated. 
This only happens when the `SizeToContent` flag is set.
Any ideas why? How can I force the window to calculate the height automatically when it is loaded?

```
<Window x:Class="TestGridRow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="Height">
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row0" Height="6*"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="row1" Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" xml:space="preserve">
        Hallo
        Hallo
        Hallo
        </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Background="Red" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: 3.5 or 4?  I think there's some issues with the Grid and row size calculation in 4.

Comment: Basically 2010/4, but the same happens in 2008/3.5.

Comment: In the Constructor for the class you might be able to set the SizeToContent setting after render using the Dispatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably just set the `SizeToContent` to `Manual` in the `Window.Loaded` event. This will allow the framework to determine the correct size of the window, and afterwards force the rows to calculate the height correctly.

```
private void Window_Loaded ( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
{
   SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the Grid a value for Height or MinHeight:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" MinHeight="100">
  ...
</Grid>
```

This is not a bug: you set the rows to be 60%/40% of the height of the window, but also set the window to size itself to its children(`SizeToContent="Height"`).